# Android stop views redrawing when the virtual keyboard is opened

Tags: android

I have a fragment that is displayed on top of a FrameLayout in an activity, the Fragment has a white background that covers the content. When the soft keyboard is opened the Fragment is redrawing itself and losing its white background.

The behaviour only occurs on a physical device, it works as expected on the emulator.

How can i stop the keyboard from redrawing the fragment when it is opened? I am using "adjustPan".